# Long vs Short Earth Connection for Single Phase Motor vs 3 Phase Motor Frame

Tags: ground, safety, short-circuit, induction-motor

**What is the correct way of grounding single phase motor frame if I have to choose between two options:**

(1) Short to earth connection: from the frame to nearest grounding rod. See below the schematic. 
(2) Long to earth connection: from the frame to the ground bus power panel that the motor is supplied by (which could be just far away. See below.

I think (1) is not enough since it does not have a fault current path with the neutral if the hot conductor (s) energizes the frame.

I see the fault current path as a way to trip the breaker or the fuse

However, I just do not understand why this is not the case with 3 phase motors

**In 3 phase motors, you don't usually have a neutral, and if the frame is energized, then how will the trip happen ?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHiMGQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff4z6c.png)</sup>

Comment: An exception with VFD driven motors it must be grounded back to the VFD to couple back the noise generated by the VFD.

Answer (score 1):

If the motor is fed from a star (wye) connected transformer then there should be a neutral to earth link at the transformer. This is standard in Europe. (You have omitted your location from your user profile so I can't be more specific.) This neutral link references all three phases to earth so that 230 V RMS appears on each phase.
Now if a phase to frame fault occurs then the protective device on that phase should trip.

The single-phase motor you have described has the neutral wire but the fault current (in the event of a phase to frame fault) does not return through the neutral so the protection behaves the same as in the three-phase situation.

If the motor were fed from a delta-connected secondary supply then the first phase to frame fault would be tolerated and the fusing would not trip.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8dlYC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) A star (wye) connected 3-phase supply system with three voltmeters or lamps will pull the star/wye point to neutral potential. (b) With delta-connected supply the situation will be the same even though there is no star point in the transformer or generator output.*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgoN6x.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. With a single earth fault the system can still run but a second phase fault will cause a trip.*

Note that earth fault detection circuits can be designed using the arrangement of Figure 2 and can be used to signal a fault (where reliability is most important) or trip immediately.

Comment: What type of protective device are you referring to? the overload or the short circuit?

Comment: I did not get it why the protective device (on that phase) should trip if phase to frame fault occurrs

Comment: (1) The protective device - a fuse or MCB (minature circuit breaker) doesn't care what kind of fault it is. It just opens the circuit once a specified current is exceeded for a specified time. (2) It's not clear which section of my answer your second comment refers to. Please clarify.